# search based on opportunity product field

Tags: search, global-search

I save metadata on each product line item - currently save in the description field.

I'm looking for a way to search base on the field value via the global search.

Seems like it's not supported

Any ideas for alternative solutions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not all object and fields are searchable, there is a [reference table](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=search_fields_lex.htm&type=5) to determine which records you can find with Salesforce search.

for example, Opportunity, in lightning experience:

> Description
>
> Opportunity Name

and in Classic:

> Description
>
> Opportunity Name
>
> Account Name
>
> All custom auto-number fields and custom fields that are set as an external ID
>   (You don't need to enter leading zeros.)
>
> All custom fields of type text, text area, long text area, rich text area, email, and phone

mkae sure your field meets the above criteria.

For further details on how search works, you can check [Set Up and Manage Salesforce Search](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=search_setup_parent.htm&type=5)